# Não consigo Alinhar divs

Tags: html, css

Sou iniciante na área e estou tentando montar um layout com elementos flutuantes usando html e css, porém quando eu crio a segunda div ela não fica alinhada com a div original. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
* {
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 background: #f3f3f3;
}

.barra-navegacao{
 background: #fff;
 height: 45px;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
}

#logo{
 font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
 float: left;
 margin-right: : 500px;
 position: fixed;
 left: 50px;
}

.vermelho{
 color: #de4444;
}

.area{
 width: 720px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu{ 
 float: right;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-left: 100px;
}
   

.flutuantes{
 border: 1px solid grey;
 height: 350px;
 width: 500px;
 float: left;
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="barra-navegacao">
  <div class="area">
  <h1 id="logo"><span class="vermelho">MMA</span>Store - Sua loja de MMA</h1>
  <div id="menu">
   <a href="produtos.html">Produtos |</a>
   <a href="exclusivos.html"> Exclusivos |</a>
   <a href="produtos.html"> Atletas |</a>
   <a href="exclusivos.html"> Encomendas</a>

  </div>
 </div>

  <div class="flutuantes"> <h2>Flutuantes<h2></div>

  <div class="flutuantes"> <h2>Flutuantes<h2></div>
```

Comment: Como o @hugocsl já deu uma boa resposta para você, recomendo que você dê uma olhada em CSS Grid, pois facilita a manipulação de layouts [aqui tem um bom tutorial](https://www.origamid.com/projetos/css-grid-layout-guia-completo/) =)

Comment: Muito obrigado, darei uma olhada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seu problema é que dentro da `div area` vc tem um o elemento `logo` com `position fixed`, o que eu posso te adiantar é que essa estrutura de layout está meio que comprometida, pq muito provavelmente quando o conteúdo crescer e a pagina tiver scroll vc pode ter algum problema...

De qualquer forma para corrigir é só colocar `overflow: auto` na `div area`, isso vai mudar o escopo dos elementos que estão dentro dela e  ela vai passar a ***"assumir os filhos"*** (mesmo que tenham `float` ou `position`) rss

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código ajustado.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

.barra-navegacao{
  background: #fff;
  height: 45px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

#logo{
  font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
  float: left;
  margin-right: : 500px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
}

.vermelho{
  color: #de4444;
}

.area{
  width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

#menu{ 
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
    

.flutuantes{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 350px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="barra-navegacao">
    <div class="area">
    <h1 id="logo"><span class="vermelho">MMA</span>Store - Sua loja de MMA</h1>
    <div id="menu">
      <a href="produtos.html">Produtos |</a>
      <a href="exclusivos.html"> Exclusivos |</a>
      <a href="produtos.html"> Atletas |</a>
      <a href="exclusivos.html"> Encomendas</a>

    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="flutuantes"> <h2>Flutuantes<h2></div>

    <div class="flutuantes"> <h2>Flutuantes<h2></div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado!

Comment: @MarlonJohnson depois tira um tempinho para estudar sobre display flex, ai vc vai ficar muito menos dependente de ficar usando position e float para fazer layout. Se vc acha que a resposta resolveu o problemas considere marca-la com aceita nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas ao lado da resposta. Depois se vc achar que deve pode remover o aceite ou mudar para alguma resposta que vc ache mais adequada.